# IndexError: list index out of range while running KMeans in Python

Tags: python, k-means

I would like to run Kmeans clustering algorithm with five features. (K=4) However, I am getting an Index error saying this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File
> "C:\....py", line 756,
> in <module>
>     plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10) 
>     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's a code snippet that's generating error:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroid = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,7), dpi=100)

colors = ["r.","b.","y."]

df_clustering = []

for i in range(len(X)):
   print ("ID:", df_features['id'].loc[[i]].values[0], "coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
   df_clustering.append((df_features['id'].loc[[i]].values[0], labels[i]))

   # below line is generating an error
   plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10)
```

Comment: Apparently, one of the list `X` or `labels` in that statement is out of range when indexing. Check the length of `X`  and `labels` to make sure your call is correct.

Comment: Both of them returns 136, and values returned when k=3 was the same. Also, when index value is 27, it stopped there. What could be other possible reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using 4 clusters, but `colors` is of length 3. So for any data point being assigned to cluster 4 (i.e., `labels[i] == 3`), there will be an `IndexError`.